# Hosting a nodejs+express app to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, git, express, heroku

I have a nodejs app and I want to push it to heroku. 
I have followed up the instructions, but anyway when i open the deployed website it gives an "Application error"
[image: The files]

Who knows how to deploy to heroku nodejs app?

Comment: What method do you use to deploy ? Did you check the log to see any errors ?

Comment: Refer this link https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-app-to-heroku